# State Manager not persisting/retrieving data

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi 1.1.1

I am trying to persist a byte [] using the ​[State Manager](https://nifi.apache.org/developer-guide.html).

```
private byte[] lsnUsedDuringLastLoad;


@Override
    public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context,
            final ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {
...

...

...
​final StateManager stateManager = context.getStateManager();
try {
StateMap stateMap = stateManager.getState(Scope.CLUSTER);
final Map<String, String> newStateMapProperties = new HashMap<>();
newStateMapProperties.put(ProcessorConstants.LAST_MAX_LSN,
new String(lsnUsedDuringLastLoad));
logger.debug("Persisting stateMap : "
+ newStateMapProperties);
stateManager.replace(stateMap, newStateMapProperties,
Scope.CLUSTER);
} catch (IOException ioException) {
logger.error("Error while persisting the state to NiFi",
ioException);
throw new ProcessException(
"The state(LSN) couldn't be persisted", ioException);
}

...
...
...
}
```

I don't get any exception or even a log error entry, the processor continues to run.
The following load code always returns a null value(Retrieved the statemap : {})for the persisted field :

```
try {
                    stateMap = stateManager.getState(Scope.CLUSTER);
                    stateMapProperties = new HashMap<>(stateMap.toMap());

                    logger.debug("Retrieved the statemap : "+stateMapProperties);


                    lastMaxLSN = (stateMapProperties
                            .get(ProcessorConstants.LAST_MAX_LSN) == null || stateMapProperties
                            .get(ProcessorConstants.LAST_MAX_LSN).isEmpty()) ? null
                            : stateMapProperties.get(
                                    ProcessorConstants.LAST_MAX_LSN).getBytes();


                    logger.debug("Attempted to load the previous lsn from NiFi state : "
                            + lastMaxLSN);
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    logger.error("Couldn't load the state map", ioe);
                    throw new ProcessException(ioe);
                }
```

I am wondering if the ZK is at fault or have I missed something while using the State Map !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for replace say:

"Updates the value of the component's state to the new value if and only if the value currently is the same as the given oldValue."

https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/components/state/StateManager.java#L79-L92

I would suggest something like this:

```
if (stateMap.getVersion() == -1) {
  stateManager.setState(stateMapProperties, Scope.CLUSTER);
} else {
  stateManager.replace(stateMap, stateMapProperties, Scope.CLUSTER);
}
```

The first time through when you retrieve the state, the version should be -1 since nothing was ever stored before, and in that case you use setState, but then all the times after that you can use replace.

Comment: It worked like a breeze, however, I am still wondering behind the doc. for the replace() method :| - what could be the rationale ?

Comment: I don't know the reasoning, but in the replace implementation it has...  if (stateMap.getVersion() == -1L) {
                // state has never been set so return false
                return false;
            }

Comment: After using StateManager myself I think the idea behind replace() is, to control if another node or task has updated the map in the meantime. Consider this situation: one of your tasks get the current state, does something with it and update it later. While this task 1 was holding the status it could have been updated by another task (task 2). Updates from task 1 would override whatever task 2 did.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. After successfully using nifi state map in stateful computation. I found that this statemap can only be initialized once and after that the key fixed or you need to re-set the state to change keys.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind `replace()` and the return value is, to be able to react on conflicts. Another task on the same or on another node (in a cluster) might have changed the state in the meantime. When `replace()` returns false, you can react to the conflict, sort out, what can be sorted out automatically and inform the user when it can not be sorted out.

This is the code I use:

```
/**
 * Set or replace key-value pair in status cluster wide. In case of a conflict, it will retry to set the state, when the given
 * key does not yet exist in the map. If the key exists and the value is equal to the given value, it does nothing. Otherwise
 * it fails and returns false.
 * 
 * @param stateManager that controls state cluster wide.
 * @param key of key-value pair to be put in state map.
 * @param value of key-value pair to be put in state map.
 * @return true, if state map contains the key with a value equal to the given value, probably set by this function.
 *      False, if a conflict occurred and key-value pair is different. 
 * @throws IOException if the underlying state mechanism throws exception.
 */
private boolean setState(StateManager stateManager, String key, String value) throws IOException {
        boolean somebodyElseUpdatedWithoutConflict = false;
        do {
            StateMap stateMap = stateManager.getState(Scope.CLUSTER);

            // While the next two lines run, another thread might change the state.
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(stateMap.toMap()); // Make mutable
            String oldValue = map.put(key, value);

            if(!stateManager.replace(stateMap, map, Scope.CLUSTER)) {
                // Conflict happened. Sort out action to take
                if(oldValue == null)
                    somebodyElseUpdatedWithoutConflict = true; // Different key was changed. Retry
                else if(oldValue.equals(value))
                    break; // Lazy case. Value already set
                else
                    return false; // Unsolvable conflict
            }
        } while(somebodyElseUpdatedWithoutConflict);
        return true;
}
```

You can replace the part after `// Conflict happened...` with whatever conflict resolution you need.